# Insert a list into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have this list I am trying to insert into my database. I have tried many other methods I found on Google or here but none seems to work.

```
results = ['match number 1','match number 2','match number 3']
query = "INSERT INTO round1 (details) VALUES ("
query = query+"'"+results+"')"
x = conn.cursor()
x.execute(query)
conn.commit()
```

I keep getting this error

```
Type Error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you inserting `results` as *one* column, as multiple columns or as multiple rows? Your query suggests you are inserting just one column, and I am guessing you want multiple rows.

Comment: yes in one column as multiple rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use concatenation, use SQL parameters:

```
query = "INSERT INTO round1 (details) VALUES (%s)"
c = conn.cursor()
c.executemany(query, [(r,) for r in results])
```

Your code tried to concatenate a whole list with a string; you can only concatenate strings to strings. But to insert multiple rows for each value, you need to run an `INSERT` statement *per entry* in `results`.

Using SQL parameters here has several advantages:

- You leave quoting the value up to the database, avoiding SQL injection attacks.
- The database can reuse the query plan for the SQL statement, optimizing database performance.
- You can use `cursor.executemany()` to run the same query with different values, all with one call.

The `cursor.executemany()` call here takes each 'row' found in the second argument, taking the values from each row to run a separate `INSERT` statement.

Comment: only started learning python about 2 weeks ago, i am getting this when i used your code "ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1")"

Comment: What database adapter are you using here? I was assuming MySQLdb, which uses `%s` as parameters syntax, but different adapters have different styles. See `modulename.paramstyle` and the documentation.

Comment: it is mysqldb from lxml import html
import requests
import MySQLdb
import itertools

Comment: Then doublecheck your syntax; as posted in my answer the query would work.

Answer (score 0):

> i keep getting this error Type Error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

First of all, what you're doing wrong is trying to concatenate str and list objects. You can't do that: you can only concatenate a string with a string.

Secondly, use prepared statements, instead of string manipulation to communicate with your database. It will be less code for you, and more secure.